# Does this categorical quotient exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

Look at the example 3 in the following picture and also its orbits. 
 [image]

It is from the book: *Algebraic Geometry IV: Linear Algebraic Groups Invariant Theory* by A.N. Parshin，I.R. Shafarevich. The author treat it as a counterexample which categorical quotient does not exist.

But in another book, *Actions and Invariants of Algebraic Groups*, Second Edition,by Walter Ricardo Ferrer Santos, Alvaro Rittatore, there is a similar example which has categorical quotient, but no orbit space or geometric quotient.

> Does this action have categorical quotient?

I think yes by intuition, but can not show the exact reason.

Comment: Can you retype the relevant part? This makes it more searchable and accessible, and in this case, the image is blurry and hard to read. I would also trim the image only to the relevant part (which, after retyping the relevant parts, would just be Figure 4, though even there, an ASCII art version would probably be clearer than the blurry image.)

Comment: There is a matrix in my question, it is hard for me to draw it , you can see it in Jesko Hüttenhain's answer, his U is my group G, it acts in k$^2$ naturaly.

Comment: It seems that there is no good criterion to make the categorical quotient exist, we must work by definition. For my question, we can from f(x+uy, y) = f(x, y) to get f is independent with x, so we get the categorical quotient π(x,y) = y, from k$^2$ to k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get your own right answer. The action your are considering is $a\cdot (x,y)=(x+ay, y)$. This action cannot have a geometric quotient $\pi:k^2 Y$ because the quotient morphism $\pi$ should be continous, and therefore cannot separate the points of the x-axis, that are fixed points (and hence each one is an orbit).

However, I should point out that in  Vinberg and Popov's book  it is NOT claimed that this action has not a categorical quotient. What they state is that the geometric quotient does not exist (in their book X/G is the notation for the geometric quotient)

You can find an example of an action without a categorical quotient in my book with Ferrer Santos. This example was taken from Vinberg and Popov's book (right after definition 4.5. without proof: $L_2(k)$ being the 2x2 matrices).

Comment: You are right,. In Vinberg and Popov's book, the group in example 3 is borrowed to act on a 2×2 matrix space, not the same example. I do not notice that.